# Facing difficulty in setting sorting rules using RuleBasedCollator in java

Tags: java, sorting, selenium-webdriver

I am doing automation where trying to perform below :

1. Getting list of string values from web page which is already in ascending.
2. I want to make sure that if web page given values ascending order is correct or not.
3. So I am storing values in array which I collected from web page.
4. After collecting values from web page, I am sorting that array but some how I don't see same values in ascending order after sort using java code.

These are values which I get after ascending from website :

```
_john
_tim
11
111
5
A
aaa
aaa
AI-1
Android
API
AppName
asd
AWS
AWS
awstest
AWSTest1type
Azure
```

And after sorting using java collection, I am getting like below :

```
 _john
    _tim
    11
    111
    5
    A
   AI-1
   API
   AWS
   AWS
  Android
  AppName
  Azure
  aaa
  aaa
```

Code I am using to sort :

```
String rules = "< '_' < 1 < 2 <3 <4 < 5 < A < a";
        Collections.sort(myStringArray, new RuleBasedCollator(rules));
```

May I missing anything in above rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the order of ASCII Character set where 'Z' comes first than 'a'

---

RuleBasedCollator checks only the first letter of the string to sort. As the rule set by you is (A < a). It lists all string starting with the Capital letters first and then comes the small letters.

As your list contains string starting with special characters, I suggest to create two list to sort. One for the string starting with special characters and then other list containing all other values. Sort these two list separately and then merge the sorted lists. I have tried the below code and it works fine

```
// Input list
List<String> name = new ArrayList<String>();


    final String[] specialChars = { "_", ">" }; 
    List<String> specCharList = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> strList = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> finalList = new ArrayList<String>();
    String rules = "< '_' < '>' ";

    boolean isSpec = false ;
    for(String names : name) {
        isSpec = false ;
        for(int i=0;i<specialChars.length;i++) {
            if(names.startsWith(specialChars[i])) {
                // System.out.println("Name : "+names);
                isSpec = true ;
            }
        }  
      // to sort special char list and normal list
       if(isSpec) {
           specCharList.add(names);
       } else {
           strList.add(names);
       }
    }


    try {
        // To sort special character list
        Collections.sort(specCharList, new RuleBasedCollator(rules));
        // Add the sorted list to finallist
        finalList.addAll(specCharList);

        // to sort other list
        Collections.sort(strList, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
        // Add the sorted list to finallist
        finalList.addAll(strList);

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println("Final Output List --------");
    for(String names : finalList) {
        System.out.println(names);
    }
```

Comment: Can you please explain in detail?

Comment: Thank you answer, you specified rule only for special characters? Do I need to add separate rules for alphanumeric?

Comment: Numberic/Alphanumeric strings  will get sorted under "Collections.sort(strList, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);".

Comment: Hey it works like charm. Thank you so much my friend.

Comment: For me it is also required to understand logic. can you please tell me what this rule specify?